# tocloft and list of figures: get rid of page number of apperance

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to get rid of the page number of appearance in my List of figures, since it should only reference to the sources of the figures. I am working with tocloft. Following code gets rid of the first number, but I have the feeling, that it is the right way to handle that problem.

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]